# 7TB SSD cannot be formatted and restored, shows as 58GB

Tags: ssd, cmd.exe, formatting, format, diskpart

I had problems with my drive, I presumed that it was due to it being in exFAT. Started deep formatting with cmd, but since it was taking forever, I unplugged the drive.

I am now unable to use it.

Running diskpart as admin, I can't format it, nor clean it.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: WTF is a deep format?  Zero the first 1k of the disk, repartition it and start again.

Comment: What make and model is the SSD?

Comment: How much did it cost? Less than about $£€1,000 & you got a fake.

Comment: No real 7TB SSD ever comes formatted as exFAT. Ask for the money back, if possible.

Comment: What brand is this SSD and where did you buy it? It sounds like you got a 64GB drive with a 7TB sticker on it.

Comment: IMHO this is fake SSD, which is sell as 7TB, but internally is (for example) 64GB

Comment: @Tetsujin, Samsung and Dell ask >6k $/euro/pound.....

Comment: @RomeoNinov an 8TB Samsung SATA is "only" £600 from a well known UK computer company. That would be about the lower bounds for current prices though. https://www.scan.co.uk/products/8tb-samsung-870-qvo-25-ssd-sata-iii-6gb-s-mjx-mlc-v-nand-8gb-cache-read-560mb-s-write-530mb-s-98k-88 7TB sounds like a weird number for either an old device or a fake one, so the legitimacy of this one would depend on where, when and how much was paid.

Comment: @Mokubai I bet you a dinner at the Gordon Ramsey's restaurant of your choice the OP's was $100 or less ;)

Comment: @Mokubai This is a offbrand from aliexpress. Quite likely that it's a fake. can't even get this to work. I'll return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fake drive hat cost me little money, but tons of trouble. Be careful, kids!